# Validation "OR" condition

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I want to be able to check if the file uploaded is either an image or a file with MIME type `video/mp4` (mp4 video). However, I'm not sure how to do this as it would require an "OR" condition in the validation.

Right now, all I have is the image check:

```
$validator = Validator::make(array('fileUpload' => $fileUpload), [
    'fileUpload' => 'required|image',
]);
```

How can I add the "OR" condition to also check if the file has a MIME type of `video/mp4`?

Answer (score 2):

You could also use the [**MIME Types rule**](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/validation#rule-mimetypes) or [**MIME rule**](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/validation#rule-mimes) :

```
$validator = Validator::make(
    ['fileUpload' => $fileUpload],
    ['fileUpload' => 'required|mimetypes:image/jpeg,image/bmp,image/png,video/mp4']
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own validation rule to do this:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/validation#custom-validation-rules

Yours might look something like this:

```
Validator::extend('img_or_mp4', function ($attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator) {
    return X; // Check the data in $value to see if it's an image or mp4
});
```

Then your rule will be:

```
    'fileUpload' => 'required|img_or_mp4',
```

Comment: Wouldn't that just mean rewriting the `image` validation rule within this custom validation rule?

Comment: It means you wouldn't use `image` but would write your own logic that does something similar to what `image` does, PLUS allows for an mp4.